Angular 18: compilation fails due to error in piscina library
I am trying to update a project to Angular 18, but I get this error when I tried to build:
    ✘ [ERROR] Angular compilation initialization failed. [plugin angular-compiler]

  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ParseForTypeErrors')
      at createAngularCompilerHost (/Users/igino/Desktop/angular-electron/node_modules/@angular/build/src/tools/esbuild/angular/angular-host.js:98:57)
      at AotCompilation.initialize (/Users/igino/Desktop/angular-electron/node_modules/@angular/build/src/tools/esbuild/angular/compilation/aot-compilation.js:51:67)
      at async initialize (/Users/igino/Desktop/angular-electron/node_modules/@angular/build/src/tools/esbuild/angular/compilation/parallel-worker.js:33:50)
      at async /Users/igino/Desktop/angular-electron/node_modules/piscina/dist/worker.js:146:26

I am using Node v22.2.0
I already tried to override piscina version to 4.5.1 as indicated here, but I had no luck

Any solution to this?  I'm running into the same issue.

Make sure you're using a compatible version of TypeScript.
Angular: 18.1.x || 18.2.x
TypeScript: >=5.4.0 <5.6.0
Source: https://angular.dev/reference/versions#actively-supported-versions
